# making permanent changes to the path of cookies

Tags: cookies, tomcat6

Where can I make changes if I want to make permanent changes in cookie-path value for my website. will that be in context.xml or web.xml or will that be using newCookie.setPath() method only? The server is Tomcat 6.0. I did look online but have not found anything, to the point.

Its just that there is some problem with the session tracking and admin thinks that this requires changing path of my session cookies from /site-folder to /. Is he wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be something considered good programming trick, but to change the sessioncookiepath value, web-app>METAINF>context.xml file is the place. For perticulary my problem, putting following code helped: Context sessionCookiePath=""   This might be due to my website structure.